# Get the latest date of email in a folder

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I get the latest date in a folder with emails inside it?

Is there a method in VBA-Outlook that gets the latest date of an emails?

For Example: I have three mails inside the folder with the same content but differect Received Time. How do I get the latest email from the three?

Answer (score 5):

You can sort the `Items` collection in descending order:

```
Set colItems = objFolder.Items
colItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
```

Retrieve the first item using the [GetFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff861538.aspx) method. The date of this item is the latest date in the folder.

Add some error checking for empty folders and items of unexpected types.

Comment: @Axel Kemper. Thanks. But what kind of variable is colItems? Is it an integer or an Outlook.item?

Comment: ++ However you do not need `GetFirst`

Comment: GetFirst returns "nothing", if the collection is empty. Item(1) would throw an "index out of bounds" error in this case. Basically, a matter of taste. And I usually do not remember if Items are indexed zero-based or one-based.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim myItems As Items
    Dim myItem As MailItem

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    myItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True

    If myItems.Count > 0 Then
        Set myItem = myItems.Item(1)

        Debug.Print myItem.ReceivedTime
    Else
        Msgbox "This folder doesn't have any emails/items"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Siddhart Rout. But its getting the email with the oldest date. Where do I put  the myItems.Sort "ReceivedTime"? Is it before the For Each statement where it loops thru every email or inside the For Each statement?

Comment: You don't use a For Loop :) `1` Are you sure you have set the correct folder "Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)"

Comment: Copy my code as it is and paste it in Outlook. Change folder as required and then run the code

Comment: Yup. I used For Each because I have to loop thru each mails and open the latest mail.

Comment: But that is what I am trying to tell you.. you do not need to loop. As far as opening that email is concerned you can work with `myItem`

Comment: Yes @Siddharth Rout. But I have to get the email that has a tag inside the content. If there are two emails that has the same tag, I have to sort them by latest date then get the latest email and open it. Sorry, I didn't explain it completely earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89135/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-bigbryan).